# PhantomJS парсинг сайта

Tags: javascript, node.js, парсер, phantomjs

Есть готовый скрипт парсинга на питоне. Мне надо перевести этот код на JS.

Там есть строка:

```
filename = "files/captcha/" + item['idCaptcha'] + ".jpg"
temp_filename, headers = urllib.request.urlretrieve(item['captcha_url'], filename)
copyfile(filename, "/var/www/html/static/captcha/" + item['idCaptcha'] + ".jpg")
```

Есть метод .urlretrieve(). Как я понял метод копирует файл с item['captcha_url'] в директорию filename.

Теперь вопрос, как это реализовать это в phantomJS?

Answer (score 1):

Не понятно, при чём здесь PhantomJS, если речь идёт о том, что нужно сохранить удаленный файл локально. Это вопрос к NodeJS

Вот одно из решений и, на сколько я знаю, python не асинхронен из коробки, в отличии от NodeJS. По этому реализация и интерфейс данной функции будут отличаться.

```
// модуль для выполниния http(s) - запросов
const https = require('https');

// модуль для работы с файловой системой
const fs = require('fs');

/**
 * Загрузит файл с url и сохранит по указанному пути
 * @param {String} url Расположение удалённого файла (только http и https)
 * @param {String} filename Расположение локального файла
 * @return {Promise<void>}
 */
function urlRetrieve(url, filename) {
  // т.к. все операции выполняются асинхронно, возвращаем не результат, а обещание
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    // выполняем запрос
    https.get(url, response => {
      // если статус код не равен 200, то качать нечего
      if (response.statusCode !== 200) {
        return reject(`HTTP Status code is ${response.statusCode}`);
      }

      // счётчик кол-ва полученных данных
      let length = 0;

      // данные будут аккумулироваться в этом буфере
      const buffer = Buffer.alloc(parseInt(response.headers['content-length']));

      // callback - на чтение входящего потока
      response.on('data', chunk => buffer.fill(chunk, length, length = length + chunk.length));

      // callback - на ошибку чтения
      response.on('error', error => reject(error));

      // когда всё прочитано, сохраняем буфер в файл и вызываем обещание
      response.on('end', () => fs.writeFile(filename, buffer, error => error ? reject(error) : resolve()));
    });
  });
}

urlRetrieve('https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/7c8ca964-7728-4af5-9cc5-4fe30e534e71/scale-to-width-down/800', '/tmp/img.jpg')
  // в этом блоке код, который может работать со скаченной картинкой
  .then(() => console.log('done'))
  // здесь обработка ошибок
  .catch(error => console.error(error));
```